# In Vim why is eol assigned to a key ($) to the right of the key (^) for bol?

Tags: vim

Is there a logical reason why eol ($) is assigned to a key which is to the left of the key (^) bol?

Physically speaking "eol" is on the right and "bol" is on the left, would it not make more sense for the key maps to be reversed to match what is on screen?

I'm really asking why the key mapping is this way round, I must be missing something...

Comment: Why do you presume that the location of the keys was of any influence in the decision? For starters, there are different keyboard layouts in the world...

Comment: Had location been a factor, it would have been even more screwed up on the keyboard vi was written on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg

Comment: My assumption was that there was a reason other than keyboard layout for the chosen mappings.

Comment: I just didn't got one thing: what this has to do with Vim?

Comment: @Sidyll: $ and ^ are the Vim key mappings for EOL and BOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regex, `^` matches the start of a string and `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: I think I'll remap them to be the other way round.

Comment: This is going to get extremely confusing when you become fluent in regular expressions.  That being said, it is your configuration, so do whatever makes you most productive.

Comment: yeah maybe, I don't know regex other than the basics. I always have to think for a second when I do EOL/BOL. I'll ponder the pros/cons.

Answer (score 3):

By chance, it makes perfect sense on a French keyboard layout.

`^` and `$` are right next `Enter`, and they are respectively left and right.

[image]

So you might want to switch to French keyboard layout. :)

Comment: hmm… this `^` is a dead key (circumflex accent) and the ASCII `^` is on AltGr-9.

Comment: @Benoit : you are right but it works if you type twice on this key in a row. The second key press will generate the `^` character and cursor will move at first character of the line. So it kinda works. (and this is what I use, because it is easier than AltGr-9) It is quite handy to toggle between bol and eol quickly.

Answer (score 1):

> Physically speaking "eol" is on the right and "bol" is on the left

There are languages that go from right to left. Your above statement would not be true for those.

Comment: Yes, but all programming languages (that I am aware of) are written in English, like Ruby of Japanese (R->L?) origin. So I would assume this was not the reason for the key mappings.

Comment: @kris: VIM is a text editor and can be used to do editing normal text docs and not only programs. And maybe there is some reason for the mapping. I was just pointing out that your assumption is not correct for all the cases. As michaelmichael said, this should have been a comment and not an answer.